# Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^4+y^4}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^4+y^4}$$

I tried checking along the $x-axis$, the result is $0$

I tried checking along the $y-axis$, the result is still $0$

I tried checking along the line $y=x$, the result is still $0$!

The numerator always becomes $0$ in any substituion, and so I think the limit is $0$ but I see no way of proving it. The bottom cannot be factored either?

Comment: OK, now check along the line $y=kx$. What is the limit? How do you **now** explain your earlier observations?

Comment: I would guess that the quotient of two homogenous polynomials of the same degree has a limit at the origin iff the denominator is a constant times the numerator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**: Try two paths: $y = 2x$ and $x = 2y$ they should simplify and get two different constants.

Comment: How did you think of this answer? It works, but were there any clues that told you to pick these?

Comment: Its the simplest choices to be honest...

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, usually I try for $x,y$ axis first, then I'll try for this next, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=mx$. Then:
$$\frac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^4+y^4} = \frac{mx^4-m^3x^4}{x^4+m^4x^4} = \dfrac{m-m^3}{1+m^4}$$

$m=0$ and $m=1$ and even $m=-1$ gives you $0$, which is why you couldn't disprove the limit.